# Databases for gene regulatory network graphs?

Tags: bioinformatics, gene-expression, gene-regulation, network

What databases are available for gene regulatory network graphs starting from a given gene? For example, starting from p53 gene, where can I find a gene regulatory network image that can be exported or embedded to another website?

Answer (score 10):

For a free resource, try [GenMAPP](http://www.genmapp.org/default.html). Commercial products like [Ingenuity Pathway Analysis](http://www.ingenuity.com/products/pathways_analysis.html) do the same thing with prettier graphics and a curated approach to network-building, but access can be expensive if you're not affiliated with an institution that will foot the bill.

Answer (score 8):

If you can't afford ingenuity, KEGG has branched out into regulatory networks as well.  Here's the link to their version of the pathway.

http://www.genome.jp/kegg/pathway/hsa/hsa04115.html

Its free to use as a reference and for academic research.

Comment: How did you get to this page? I want exactly the same thing for other genes but I keep winding up at pages that look like this: http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?ko:K02583 and don't know where to go

Comment: i can click on 'pathway menu' and then use the box to search for my genes and get more diagrams like this one.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend you to visit **[Pathguide](http://pathguide.org/)** to get a sense of how vast is the catalog of Pathway Databases. Looking into the category **[Pathway Diagrams](http://pathguide.org/#4)** or in **Transcription Factors / Gene Regulatory Networks** should help in your task.

I would start by looking at these DataBases:

- GeneMania
- BioCarta
- WikiPathways
- Reactome

If you are working with a species other than human, perhaps you'll find a more suitable database in PathGuide.

Good luck!

PS: Sorry New user limitations impede me to post more than two links :/

Comment: You can write the links into the comments and someone else can edit your answer.